# "To do as he did" vs. "to do as he had done"

Tags: american-english, british-english, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

> He advised me/ to do as he did/ but I did not pay any attention/ to his advice. /(No error)

The answer is no error , but I think the sentence should say "to do as he had done".  Why is "as he did" acceptable?

Comment: "He adviced me" is an error.

Comment: Whether it should be *did* or *had done* depends on the timing of events. Neither is wrong.

Comment: This is mis-texted by me  sorry, except this if any error ??

Comment: Peter shor , can you explain which time suitable -"did" and "had done "

Comment: "Do exactly as I do." _ _ _  -_He advised me to do as he did._ //// "Did you watch me carefully? Do exactly as I did." _ _ _ _-He  advised me to do as he had done._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of tense change due to indirect speech.

Suppose I am about to show you how to do something.  I say "**Do as I do**" and then show you the technique.  Later on you want to tell someone else what I said.  Now you have two choices:  Direct Speech or Indirect Speech.

For Direct Speech, you simply repeat what I actually said, as a quote:

> "He said '**Do as I do**.'"

For Indirect Speech, though, you do not just repeat what I actually said, so you don't have to use the exact same words, you don't have to use quotes, you generally use a 'reporting' verb such as *tell* or *ask* (or *advise*), and (most importantly here) you shift the verb tense that you use back in time, from present to simple past, to reflect that the event happened in the past:

> "He told me **to do as he did**."

Because I used the present in my original statement, you have to use the simple past in your indirect-speech version of what I said.

Of course, I might actually say "Watch this:", then show you the technique, and then say "**Do as I did.**"  This time I used the simple past tense in my statement instead of present tense.  If you want to use Indirect Speech to tell someone else what I said, you still have to shift the tense, but because my statement is already in past tense, you go to the past perfect:

> "He told me to **do as he had done**."

So, both "as he did" and "as he had done" can be correct depending on what was actually said originally.